# Dex file layout - offset and size of method_handles and call_site_ids sections

Tags: android, dex

I am trying to understand the file layout of the Dalvik executable (dex) as described [here](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dex-format#file-layout). However, I couldn't find out the offsets and length of the `call_site_ids` and `method_handles` sections described in the layout.

Most of the other sections(`string_ids`, `type_ids`) have an offset and length field in the header or are referenced as an offset from the start of file. Both `call_site_item` and `method_handle_item` seem to be referred to as an index into their respective sections elsewhere(see `VALUE_METHOD_HANDLE`[here](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dex-format#value-formats) for example).

I looked into the source code of [smali project](https://github.com/JesusFreke/smali) by @JesusFreke but it doesn't seem to handle these sections.

Am I missing anything? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call_sites_ids and method_handles sections were only added in dex version 38. The version is encoded as part of the [dex magic](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dex-format#dex-file-magic).

To find the offset and length of the call_site_ids and method_handles section, you have to look at the [map_list](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dex-format#map-list) section that's typically at the end of the file (see: map_off in the [header_item](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dex-format#header-item)).

The call_site_items are placed in the existing [encoded_array](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dex-format#encoded-array-item) data section.

Comment: Note: I've started adding support for these into smali/baksmali, but I'm not sure when I'll be able to actually get it finished :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) smali/baksmali is a great tool.

Comment: @JesusFreke, I am struggling to understand the meaning of the part of map_item section from baksmali output that does not have an interpreted view. It shows only the offsets and their binary data, and it is displayed after the map_list element. Could you please advise me on how to read it?

Comment: @Lukas if you want to ask a question, then create a question.